# Can $\pi(x)$ be obtained from this identity: $\ln(\zeta(s))=\int_2^\infty\frac{s\pi(x)}{x(x^{s}-1)}dx$ via some type of inversion?

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-number-theory, mellin-transform

I know that in Riemann's 1854 paper, he found the following:
$$\frac{\ln(\zeta(s))}{s}=\int_1^\infty{J(x)x^{-s-1}dx}\tag{1}$$
Riemann then performed Mellin inversion to get an expression for $J(x)$, and then used Mobius inversion to find an expression for $\pi(x)$

In [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U16_KTTKtb0) video, the following identity is proven:
$$\frac{\ln(\zeta(s))}{s}=\int_2^\infty\frac{\pi(x)}{x(x^{s}-1)}dx\tag{2}$$
Is there some type of integral inversion that can be performed on the RHS of $(2)$ to isolate $\pi(x)$? In a similar fashion to how Mellin inversion was done on $(1)$.

Comment: Have you heard of Perron's formula?

Comment: @TravorLZH I have not actually. How exactly is it applicable here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are essentially the same thing:

\begin{aligned}
\int_2^\infty{\pi(x)\over x(x^s-1)}\mathrm dx
&=\int_0^\infty\pi(x)x^{-1}\cdot{x^{-s}\over1-x^{-s}}\mathrm dx \\
&=\int_0^\infty\pi(x)x^{-1}\sum_{k\ge1}x^{-sk}\mathrm dx \\
&=\sum_{k\ge1}\int_0^\infty\pi(x)x^{-sk-1}\mathrm dx \\
&=\sum_{k\ge1}\int_0^\infty{\pi(x^{1/k})\over k}\cdot x^{-s-1}\mathrm dx \\
&=\int_2^\infty J(x)x^{-s-1}\mathrm dx
\end{aligned}

Comment: I didn't know that they were equivalent :o. How did you get from line 3 to line 4?

Comment: @Byte_ Fubini. To prove integrability use PNT.

Comment: @vitamind I don't mean swapping the sum and the integral. I mean the step where you get $\pi(x^{\frac{1}{k}})$ in the integral

Comment: @Byte_ It's due to a change of variable. You can consider setting $x=u^k$.

Comment: @TravorLZH I tried that and I got it. Thank you